# I get an error when get my Binary Data from Mysql db using SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I faced on problem. Here i have this Model in my SqlAlchemy

```
class ConfigArchive(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'config_archives'

    cluster_id = Column(String(SIZE_TEXT),
                        ForeignKey('clusters.cluster_id'),
                        primary_key=True,
                        index=True,
                        unique=True,
                        nullable=False)
    config_blob = Column(Binary,
                         nullable=False)
```

Then i get my binary data using filters like:

```
config_archive = self.session.query(ConfigArchive) \
            .filter(ConfigArchive.cluster_id == cluster_id).one_or_none()
```

And here I got an error like:

```
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py",line 2924, in one_or_none
     ret = list(self)
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py",line 2995, in __iter__
     return self._execute_and_instances(context)
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py",line 3018, in _execute_and_instances
     result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params) 
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",line 948, in execute
     return meth(self, multiparams, params)
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py",line 269, in _execute_on_connection
     return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
     compiled_sql, distilled_params
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
     context)
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",line 1416, in _handle_dbapi_exception
     util.reraise(*exc_info)
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
     context)
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 272, in execute
     self._handle_result(result)
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 163, in _handle_result
     self._handle_resultset()
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 651, in _handle_resultset
     self._rows = self._cnx.get_rows()[0]
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 288, in get_rows
     _eof = self.fetch_eof_columns()['eof']
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 349, in fetch_eof_columns
     for col in fields:
File ".venv/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1:
 invalid start byte
```

I try to decode my data and encode againt to utf-8, but it doesn't work. Also I set charset=utf8 for DB and It couldn't help me

I have no idea how to say SQLAlchemy to decode my binary data via 'latin-1' encoding. Because, I think, it works, cause I try this while debagging inside sources of python in

> lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py
> and decoded my binary data successfully

So, please, if some know smth about it, put your idea. Thanks

Comment: I'm using here mysql-connector-python==8.0.13 connector to DB and URL starts with sqlalchemy.url: mysql+mysqlconnector://<myUser>:<myPassword>@localhost:3306

Comment: I replaced my connector from 'mysqlconnector' to 'pymysql' and everything is fine!